# nuxt-sitemap does not find pre-rendered pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, seo

The sitemap I am trying to build is not finding the blog pages that are dynamically rendered.

##### What I am doing:

```
yarn build // running nuxi build
node .output/server/index.mjs
```

##### My setup:

nuxt: ^3.10.2, @nuxtjs/sitemap: ^5.1.0

Blog Posts are displayed, fetching happens through apollo in one of my components:

```
const { data, pending } = await useAsyncQuery(getPosts, { size: numArticlesPerPage, offset: offset.value })
```

Also, according to the docs I added to my nuxt.config.ts:

```
nitro: {
    prerender: {
      crawlLinks: true,
      routes: ["/", "/blog"], // I also tried adding the sitemap file here directly
    },
  },
```

#### What is happening:

- sitemap is being generated of all pages in my /pages directory
- prerender output shows all the necessary blog pages such as /blog/article-x, /blog/article/y being rendered. Blog pages are also visible on server
- in the sitemap none of those blog posts are being shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an API source for nuxt sitemap to generate the pages.

- For dynamic pages, see https://nuxtseo.com/sitemap/guides/dynamic-urls
- If you use Nuxt content, see https://nuxtseo.com/sitemap/integrations/content